# Keep Bitmap in ImageView when Change Fragment with ViewModel

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel, lifecycle

I have two Fragment that I bundle bitmap between them.

in **FragmentA**, I select Image From **Gallery** and **Camera** and set it in ImageView as `Bitmap`

and I will bundle that `bitmap` when I navigate to **HomeFragmrnt** and get it and Set it in ImageView in **HomeFrag** as `Bitmap` again!

**PROBLEM:**
When I leave the **FragmentA** to **FragmentB** and back again to **SettingFrag** I lose the `ImageView`!
and when I leave the **FragmentB** I lose the image again!

I know it is for `Fragment Lifecycle` and I try to use `savedInstance` but do not work!

I have `ViewModel` class for **FragmentA** and **FragmentB** ! how can I handle my problem with it ?!

if you want any code I will post it!

Thank you

Comment: This is issue is most likely related to the ViewModel, you need to show some code to understand the issue better.

Comment: @Ajeeli see the update

Comment: Where and how are you initializing your SettingViewModel? Are you passing your activity or fragment to the viewmodel?

Comment: @Ajeeli see the update

Comment: Just to make things clear, your image shows when you first run the app and enter into the SettingFragment and then it disappears when you navigation to HomeFragment or other fragment and back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem tnx @parag Pawar

I used `SharedPrefrences`! Just it!

I put the Image File in `SharedPrefrences` and get it in another Fragment! The Image Saved and everything was good!

```
   lateinit var preferences: SharedPreferences
    lateinit var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor


    companion object {
 const val PREF: String = "PREF_KEY"
        const val IMG_KEY: String = "IMG_PATH"
}



    preferences = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    editor = preferences.edit()



 editor.putString(IMG_KEY, data.data.toString())
                    editor.apply()
```

//here u get the value

```
    val sharedPreference: SharedPreferences = activity!!.getSharedPreferences(
        PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE
    )
    if (sharedPreference.contains(IMG_KEY)) {
        imgPath = sharedPreference.getString(
            IMG_KEY,
            null
        ).toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can share any data between fragments using ViewModel.

In your case, create a variable in ViewModel in the following way:

```
var mBitmap: Bitmap? = null
```

and then when you get the bitmap, assign that bitmap to above variable from your fragment

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPhotoFile!!.absolutePath)

mViewModel.mBitmap = bitmap
```

after this wherever you want to use this bitmap just call this:

```
mViewModel.mBitmap
```

for example, something like this:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(mViewModel.mBitmap)
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need anything

**Update:**

Like **Ajeeli** mentioned pass the activity instance while initializing the ViewModel

```
ViewModelProvider(activity, viewModelFactory).get(SettingViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Actually, this will only work if you're sharing ViewModel between fragments, as in using same ViewModel for both the fragments

Comment: Okay, but if you wish to store your bitmap using ViewModel then you have to use the same ViewModel in both Fragments. You can create a new ViewModel if it is feasible and then share the bitmap using it. For example, you can have NewViewModel, you'll need to initialize it within both the fragments scoping it to activity, and then you can use the same bitmap.

Comment: Yes, Don't change your existing code, Just create a New ViewModel and initialize it within the fragments you want to share your bitmap. Remember you can use as many as different ViewModlels inside your fragment. Just avoid using many.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213072/discussion-between-parag-pawar-and-sana-ebadi).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue could be that you are scoping your ViewModel to the fragment only when  it should be scoped to the activity lifecycle.

Change this:

```
ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory)
```

To:

```
ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory)
```